# Enriching Header with the value from the Transformer

Tags: java-8, spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I have a `spring integration flow.` It reads the file. The file can belong to the consumer.Once I find the consumer I want to add that **CONSUMER** to the header so later on I can use e.g. In **error handling** I can check that did I even  get the `consumer` looking at the header.

```
IntegrationsFlows.from(directorySource)
.transform(new ConsumerFinderTransformer()
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.header("CONSUMER" ,payload)
```

How do I get the payload in the `enrichHeaders` that's returned by the `ConsumerFinderTransformer` here.

I cannot find a way. Any help will be appreacited

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This one is there for you:

```
    /**
 * Add a single header specification where the value is a String representation of a
 * SpEL {@link Expression}. If the header exists, it will <b>not</b> be overwritten
 * unless {@link #defaultOverwrite(boolean)} is true.
 * @param name the header name.
 * @param expression the expression.
 * @return the header enricher spec.
 */
public HeaderEnricherSpec headerExpression(String name, String expression) {
```

So, your code should be like:

```
.enrichHeaders(h -> h.headerExpression(“CONSUMER" , “payload”)
```

Comment: Glad we have you on SO :) Thanks @Artem

Comment: But the normal API (Without expression) shouold have this method too

Comment: There is also a `headerFunction()` as variant